In Ditto Clipboard Manager, is there a quick way to open an image in my default photo viewer?
In Ditto Clipboard Manager, is there a quick way to open an image in my default photo viewer?
The best way I've found is to select it to bring it to the front of the clipboard, then open up my photo app (ImageGlass) and paste it. Or can I export it to an image file - but that's even slower.
I'm hoping there's a command I don't know about yet to just open it immediately?

You don't have to bring it to the front. You can drag it directly either to photo app or as a file to explorer, which skips a step. Or double click while the app is focused.
There's also very basic function to preview it directly in Ditto on F3. No direct "Open with" type of functionality I'm afraid.

Thanks for the quick response! You're right, bringing it to the front was a pointless step. Looks like I have to open the photo app first though, thanks! Hoping they add that feature at some point, I find myself wanting to do it every other day or so
